# How to implement a board game like interface in LibGDX using Scene2D

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm just starting with game development and decided to make a 2048 clone using `LibGDX` to learn the basics.

I started to implement it using a simple 2D array and it works, but the problem is that there aren't any animations. So, for example if there's a tile that is at position `[0][0]` and after the user swipes the screen it has to move to `[0][3]`, that transition occurs instantly (since I'm basically just updating my 2D array and re-rendering the tiles).

I was told this kind of board game-like UI is the perfect scenario to use `Scene2D`. I can very easily implement the basic 4x4 grid using Actors, but my question is, how do I correctly manage what is essentially a 2D structure using a Scene2D?

I already have the algorithms to handle where to move the tiles if the user swipes the board (left, right, top, down) and update a 2D array, but it feels like if I'm using a Scene2D, using this secondary 2D array data structure is overkill.

Right now my approach is:

1. Create a 2D array and Scene2D with my tiles
2. When user swipes, update the 2D array with the new position of the tiles
3. Iterate over the actors in the Scene2D and compare it with the tiles I have in my updated 2D array. If there have been changes, animate them (basic transition from the tile's original position to it's final position)

I just felslike I have unnecessary steps and also and unnecessary data structure here.

What would be the correct way to handle this sort of scenario?

Appreciate helpful advices, thanks!

Comment: I am not sure how you do the transition, but `Scene2D` has the `Actions` class, which lets you create those transitions easily: `actor.addAction(Actions.moveTo(x,y,duration))`

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting your tiles in a TableLayout? Just drawing it over won't work, as you have discovered.

To animate it you will need to define a MoveAction.

```
MoveToAction moveAction = new MoveToAction();
moveAction.setPosition(300f, 0f);
moveAction.setDuration(10f);
myActor.addAction(moveAction);
```

Example copied from:
http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/12/09/LibGDX-Tutorial-9-Scene2D-Part-2-Actions.aspx

I am not sure how this can be implemented if you are using TableLayout though.

Comment: Yeah, that's the main reason why I like Scene2D actually, moving objects around is pretty simple. The thing that bothers me is having to keep 2 data structures for basically the same data. I'm sure there's a better way to do this.